# Почему pygame.mixer.music.set_pos один, а pygame. mixer.music.get_pos // 1000 не изменяется

Tags: python, kivy, pygame

Использую смесь Python, Kivy и Pygame для музыки, так как не подружился с `core.audio`.

После нескольких дней мучений мне всё же удалось заставить slider изменяться по ходу проигрывания музыки. Но я столкнулся с новой проблемой. Теперь я не могу изменив положение ползунка запустить музыку с нужной секунды, она начинается оттуда же где приостановилась. Вероятнее всего проблема в Pygame. Так как `set_pos` по какой-то причине не меняет возвращаемое (`get_pos // 1000`). Код:

```
def slider_callback(self, intance, value):
    print(value)
    self.position = value
    self.lb.text = to_seconds(value)
    pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
    pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(self.position)
    print(pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() // 1000)

def playing(self, dt):
    if self.but2.background_normal == self.palki:
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() // 1000 != self.position:
            pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(self.position)
        self.position = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() // 1000
        self.sl.value = self.position

def play_but_callback(self, intance):
    if intance.background_normal == self.play:
        intance.background_normal = self.palki
        intance.background_down = self.palki
        self.f = 0
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        self.sl.value = self.position
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        intance.background_normal = self.play
        intance.background_down = self.play
        self.f = 1

class Audio_Player(App):
    def build(self):
        p = Player()
        Clock.schedule_interval(p.playing, 1)
        return p

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Audio_Player().run()
```